# Signup() function running the end else statement on program start

Tags: python, database, sqlite, customtkinter

I'm working on following a tutorial using python, bcrypt, and tkinter. When I start the program the dialogs box pops up showing error enter all info which is my last else statement. After clicking then the main program window pops up but that isnt the correct order. Creating the account doesnt seem to work either. I cant figure out where im going wrong.

```
app = customtkinter.CTk()
app.title('Login')
app.geometry('450x360')
app.config(bg='#001220')

font1 = ("Helvetica", 25, 'bold')
font2 = ('Arial', 17, 'bold')
font3 = ('Arial', 13, 'bold')
font4 = ('Arial', 13, 'bold')

conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
       username TEXT NOT NULL,
       password TEXT NOT NULL)''')

def signup():
    username = username_entry.get()
    password = password_entry.get()
    if username != '' and password != '':
        cursor.execute('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=?', [username])
        if cursor.fetchone() is not None:
            messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Username already exists.')
        else:
            encoded_password = password.encode('utf-8')
            hashed_password = bcrypt.hashpw(encoded_password, bcrypt.gensalt())
            # print(hashed_password)
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, ?)', [username,hashed_password])
            conn.commit()
            messagebox.showinfo('Success', 'Account has been created.')
    else:
         messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Enter all Info')



frame1 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(app, bg_color='#001220', fg_color='#001220', width=470, height=360)
frame1.place(x=0, y=0)

image1 = PhotoImage(
    file='C:\\Users\\cyrus\\Downloads\\data-server-racks-hub-room-with-big-data-computer-center-blue-interior-hosting-storage-hardware.png')
image1_label = Label(frame1, image=image1, bg='#001220')
image1_label.place(x=0, y=0)

signup_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(frame1, text='Sign up', text_color='#fff', bg_color='#001220')
signup_label.place(x=280, y=20)

username_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(frame1, font=font2, text_color='#fff', fg_color='#001a2e', bg_color='#121111',
                                        border_color='#004780', border_width=3, placeholder_text='Username',
                                        placeholder_text_color='#a3a3a3', width=200, height=50)
username_entry.place(x=230, y=80)

password_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(frame1, font=font2, show='*', text_color='#fff', fg_color='#001a2e',
                                        bg_color='#121111', border_color='#004780', border_width=3,
                                        placeholder_text='Password', placeholder_text_color='#a3a3a3', width=200,
                                        height=50)
password_entry.place(x=230, y=150)

signup_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(frame1,command=signup(), font=font2, text_color='#fff', text='Sign up',
                                        fg_color='#00965d',
                                        hover_color='#006e44', bg_color='#121111', cursor='hand2', corner_radius=5,
                                        width=120)
signup_button.place(x=230, y=220)

login_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(frame1, font=font4, text='Already have an account',
                                     text_color='#FFF', bg_color='#001220', )
login_label.place(x=230, y=250)

login_button = customtkinter.CTkLabel(frame1, font=font4, text_color='#00bf77', text='Login', fg_color='#001220',
                                      cursor='hand2', width=40)
login_button.place(x=395, y=250)



app.mainloop()
```

Comment: `command=signup()` should be `command=signup`. You're calling the function when you create the button, not when they click on it.